# How to add an external package to the same namespace as a local directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

Initial directory structure: (assume `__init__.py` files in directories)

```
project/
  ▾ lib/
     ▸ dir/
     ▸ package
```

I need to reuse lib.package in other projects, hence I created a python package for it and removed the directory. But installing it now as lib.package I can't import it from root of the project as it has `lib` directory there leading to a namespace collision.

Final structure:

```
▾ project/
  ▾ lib/
     ▸ dir/
```

And a package named lib.package installed in the virtualenv.

```
▾ lib/
  ▸ package/
   __init__.py
```

I looked into [pkgutil.extendpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.extend_path), but adding it to `__init__.py` of the `lib.package` python package didn't help. Are there any ways I can add both the local and virtualenv installed packages in the same namespace `lib`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds like you're trying to make `lib` a namespace package, and almost make `lib.package` a namespace package. To do that with `pkgutil`, you have to `extendpath` the `lib` package first, and then `extendpath` the `lib.package` subpackage. If you just do the latter, you'll only get one of the two `lib.package` subpackages, and `extendpath` either won't get run, or won't have anything to extend. Is that your problem, or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: @abarnert : I'm trying to have both `dir` and `package` in the same namespace `lib` even though they are in different PYTHONPATH directories. Adding `extendpath` to both `__init__.py`s you mentioned didn't work.

Comment: Can you show your actual code, instead of describing it? I'm not sure which "both `__init__.py`s" you mean. And it's also possible that you didn't use it correctly, which nobody can tell if they can't see your code. Also, please show us what your `sys.path` looks like, and what `lib.__path__` looks like after you `import lib`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 it's better to avoid this problem by choosing a name for the dependency that's unique or at least importable in your application's codebase without manipulating paths et cetera. I think the situation has improved in Python 3.4 but I'm not entirely sure here.

Furthermore, I had the same problem and decided to use unique names for another reason: when you wish to figure out where a module is from, it's quite hard when everything's namespaced under `lib`. It means the module can be from a dependency as well as the local application. It also means I can simply look at an import line and know, at all times, whether it's from my own application codebase, one of my own dependencies or an external dependency.

Comment: I think the improvement in 3.4 that you're referring to is automatic namespace packages, which mean you no longer need `pkgutil` to do what the OP is trying to do. But the basic concept of namespace packages still works the same way.